# NUT and immediate notifications

Tags: notifications, ups, nut

I would like to configure `NUT` UPS monitoring software under Linux to simply page me when the UPS goes onto battery power, and then when it returns to line power. For example, when I receive the following messages from `upsmon` in **syslog**:

```
Aug 19 05:43:27 jupsden upsmon[466]: UPS jupsden@localhost on battery
Aug 19 05:43:42 jupsden upsmon[466]: UPS jupsden@localhost on line power
```

And, maybe the best solution is a custom syslog rule?

But, all of the examples I have seen for NUT-specific configured notifications in `/etc/nut/upssched.conf` were for starting a timer when the UPS battery level reaches a certain low threshold, then passing a custom parameter to a custom script `upssched-cmd`, gracefully shutting down systems, etc. Using the "timer" approach, could I do something like the following in `upssched.conf`:

```
AT ONBATT * START-TIMER onbatterypower 0
AT ONLINE * CANCEL-TIMER onlinepower
```

...or are there some different / better NUT conf commands that would achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you could use 0-length timers, but if you want immediate reactions, there is also the `AT ... EXECUTE` syntax.

If you want pages immediately whenever the power state changes, you would use the `AT <notifytype> <upsname> EXECUTE <command>` syntax. In other words you could do something like this in `upssched.conf`:

```
CMDSCRIPT /usr/local/sbin/custom-upssched-cmd

[...]

AT ONBATT * EXECUTE start_panicking
AT ONLINE * EXECUTE panic_over
```

And your `/usr/local/sbin/custom-upssched-cmd` script (remember to `chmod a+x` it!) would then contain something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
case "$1" in
    start_panicking)
        logger -t custom-upssched-cmd "UPS went on battery power at this time"
        # add here a command to send a suitably alarming pager message
        ;;
    panic_over)
        logger -t custom-upssched-cmd "UPS reports power is back"
        # add here a command to send a calming pager message
        ;;
    *)
        logger -t custom-upssched-cmd "The administrator forgot to add a suitable message for upssched.conf command $1"
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was an elegantly simple solution. Will test this asap.